# Learn WebAssembly Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m._init is not a function

Tags: webassembly

chapter-06-interact-with-js/js-without-glue, in `Learn WebAssembly by Mike Rourke`

It does not work. Error message is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m._init is not a function`.

At First, error message is `Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" function="__memory_base" error: global import must be a number or WebAssembly.Global object`.
I replaced memoryBase and tableBase with __memory_base and __table_base in common/load-wasm.js. And it is solved.
But I get another error message `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m._init is not a function`.

```
/*
 * This file interacts with the canvas through imported functions.
 * It moves a circle diagonally across the canvas.
 */
#define BOUNDS 255
#define CIRCLE_RADIUS 50
#define BOUNCE_POINT (BOUNDS - CIRCLE_RADIUS)

bool isRunning = true;

typedef struct Circle {
  int x;
  int y;
  char direction;
} Circle;

struct Circle circle;

/*
 * Updates the circle location by 1px in the x and y in a
 * direction based on its current position.
 */
void updateCircleLocation() {
    // Since we want the circle to "bump" into the edge of the canvas,
    // we need to determine when the right edge of the circle
    // encounters the bounds of the canvas, which is why we're using
    // the canvas width - circle width:
    if (circle.x == BOUNCE_POINT) circle.direction = 'L';

    // As soon as the circle "bumps" into the left side of the
    // canvas, it should change direction again.
    if (circle.x == CIRCLE_RADIUS) circle.direction = 'R';

    // If the direction has changed based on the x and y
    // coordinates, ensure the x and y points update accordingly:
    int incrementer = 1;
    if (circle.direction == 'L') incrementer = -1;
    circle.x = circle.x + incrementer;
    circle.y = circle.y - incrementer;
}

// We need to wrap any imported or exported functions in an
// extern block, otherwise the function names will be mangled.
extern "C" {
// These functions are passed in through the importObj.env object
// and update the circle on the <canvas>:
extern int jsClearCircle();
extern int jsFillCircle(int x, int y, int radius);

/*
 * Clear the existing circle element from the canvas and draw a
 * new one in the updated location.
 */
void moveCircle() {
    jsClearCircle();
    updateCircleLocation();
    jsFillCircle(circle.x, circle.y, CIRCLE_RADIUS);
}

bool getIsRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}

void setIsRunning(bool newIsRunning) {
    isRunning = newIsRunning;
}

void init() {
    circle.x = 0;
    circle.y = 255;
    circle.direction = 'R';
    setIsRunning(true);
}
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Interact with JS without Glue Code</title>
  <script
    type="application/javascript"
    src="../common/load-wasm.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    #myCanvas {
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    #actionButtonWrapper {
      margin-top: 16px;
    }
    #actionButton {
      width: 100px;
      height: 24px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Interact with JS without Glue Code</h1>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="255" height="255"></canvas>
  <div id="actionButtonWrapper">
    <button id="actionButton">Pause</button>
  </div>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const fillCircle = (x, y, radius) => {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#fed530';
      // Face outline:
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      // Eyes:
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x - 15, y - 15, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.arc(x + 15, y - 15, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();

      // Mouth:
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x - 20, y + 10);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + 30, x + 20, y + 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = 4;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
    };

    const env = {
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 8, element: 'anyfunc' }),
      _jsFillCircle: fillCircle,
      _jsClearCircle: function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255);
      },
    };

    loadWasm('js-without-glue.wasm', { env }).then(({ instance }) => {
      const m = instance.exports;
      m._init();

      // Move the circle by 1px in the x and y every 20 milliseconds:
      const loopCircleMotion = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          m._moveCircle();
          if (m._getIsRunning()) loopCircleMotion();
        }, 20)
      };

      // Enable you to pause and resume the circle movement:
      document.querySelector('#actionButton')
        .addEventListener('click', event => {
          const newIsRunning = !m._getIsRunning();
          m._setIsRunning(newIsRunning);
          event.target.innerHTML = newIsRunning ? 'Pause' : 'Start';
          if (newIsRunning) loopCircleMotion();
        });

      loopCircleMotion();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/**
 * Returns a valid importObj.env object with default values to pass
 * into the WebAssembly.Instance constructor for Emscripten's
 * Wasm module.
 */
const getDefaultEnv = () => ({
  __memory_base: 0,
  __table_base: 0,
  memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
  table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 2, element: 'anyfunc' }),
  abort: console.log
});

/**
 * Returns a WebAssembly.Instance instance compiled from the specified
 * .wasm file.
 */
function loadWasm(fileName, importObj = { env: {} }) {
  // Override any default env values with the passed in importObj.env
  // values:
  const allEnv = Object.assign({}, getDefaultEnv(), importObj.env);

  // Ensure the importObj object includes the valid env value:
  const allImports = Object.assign({}, importObj, { env: allEnv });

  // Return the result of instantiating the module (instance and module):
  return fetch(fileName)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) return response.arrayBuffer();
      throw new Error(`Unable to fetch WebAssembly file ${fileName}`);
    })
    .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, allImports));
}
```

Following examples are the same.
- chapter-05-create-load-module/without-glue
- chapter-06-interact-with-js/js-with-glue

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your args list in the vscode default build task

"-s", "EXPORT_ALL=1"

If you look at the wat representation, you will see there is no _init... after you compile with the above added arg, it will be in there along with every other function. Quick and dirty solution.

The Emscripten FAQ says the following

> Emscripten does dead code elimination of functions that are not called
>   from the compiled code. While this does minimize code size, it can
>   remove functions that you plan to call yourself (outside of the
>   compiled code).
>
> To make sure a C function remains available to be called from normal
>   JavaScript, it must be added to the EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS using the emcc
>   command line. For example, to prevent functions my_func() and main()
>   from being removed/renamed, run emcc with:
>
> > emcc -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_main', '_my_func']"  ...

main is by default included in the list of exported functions, but init is not.

Comment: Adding the -s alone is what worked for me.  Really appreciate this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your .c file into the js output, use the following command: `emcc js-with-glue.c -O3 -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -o js-with-glue.js -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']"`

See: 
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webassembly-part-3-different-ways-to-call-the-exported-function-in-webassembly-194830bad873

Then in your html file, any place you're referencing the m._() calls that our .c file exposes it replace with result.ccall(, ,,).  Where result is the return from the promise.

Here is the source:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    Module()
      .then(result => {
        const m = result.asm;
        console.log('asm', result.asm);
        var initFunc = result.ccall('init', null, null, null       );

        // Move the rectangle by 1px in the x and y every 20 milliseconds:
        const loopRectMotion = () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            result.ccall('moveRect',null,null,null);
            if (result.ccall('getIsRunning',null,null,null)) loopRectMotion();
          }, 20)
        };

        // Enable you to pause and resume the rectangle movement:
        document.querySelector('#actionButton')
          .addEventListener('click', event => {
            const newIsRunning = !result.ccall('getIsRunning',null,null,null);
            result.ccall('setIsRunning',null,bool,newIsRunning);
            event.target.innerHTML = newIsRunning ? 'Pause' : 'Start';
            if (newIsRunning) loopRectMotion();
          });

        loopRectMotion();
      });
</script>
```